# read through entire array for keywords

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, keyword

I've been working on a keyword detection portion of my app and it all seems to be working great except for **$msg** I can only get it to read one result which is the very first message.

I'm trying to get it to read through the entire array.

If I do a **var_dump** the results are there, I'm just not sure how to read through the array.

```
try {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
        $fql    =   "SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid= me()";
        $param  =   array(
                          'method'    => 'fql.query',
                          'query'     => $fql,
                          'callback'  => ''
                          );
        $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);}   
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        }
          foreach($fqlResult as $row){
                $abt = strtolower($row['about_me']);
                $qts = strtolower($row['quotes']);
                $msg = strtolower($row['message']);//This one is causing trouble!
                $cursewrds = $abt . $msg . $qts . $status;
                $keywords = array("test","curse","words);
                $regex ="/(". implode('|', $keywords) .")/";
                $total = (preg_match_all( $regex, $cursewrds, &$matches));
```

Heres what the array looks like when I do a fql query for $msg.

```
[
  {
    "message": "test 1"
  },
  {
    "message": "test 2"
  }, 
  {
    "message": "test 3"
  },
  {
    "message": "test 4"
  }
]
```

P.S. I'm not the best at php but if I'm here I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you have going on there, but the problem seems to be your foreach loop is in the wrong place. Try:

```
foreach($fqlResult as $row){
     $abt = strtolower($row['about_me']);
     $qts = strtolower($row['quotes']);
     $msg = strtolower($row['message']);//This one is causing trouble!
     $cursewrds = $abt . $msg . $qts . $status;
     $keywords = array("test","curse","words);
     $regex ="/(". implode('|', $keywords) .")/";
     $total = (preg_match_all( $regex, $cursewrds, &$matches));

     $messages[] = $msg;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your right the foreach is out of place but that presents a different problem.
inside foreach works fine but I can't get the results outside of that?

`foreach($fqlResult as $row){
$msg = strtolower($row['message']); 
 echo $msg; // Returns entire array
 }
 echo $msg; // Returns only one result?`

Comment: $fqlResult represents an array of elements, so if you are not using some loop control structure (while, for, foreach) to parse each row, then you need to reference individual rows by their key: `echo $fqlResult[0]['message'];`

Comment: So, how would you reference all keys, or 1-10 for example? I'm looking for the best programming practice.

Comment: @Mountaininja: Not sure what you mean, using the foreach loop will give you access to every element in the array.

Comment: Seems like no matter what I do outside of the foreach loop it only returns the first result?

Comment: You are trying to get the message for every `$fqlResult`?

Comment: Yes, from the status table. No problems inside the foreach. But outside I'm only getting one result I've been through the php manual but still having problems.

Comment: No sir, just narrowing down viable possibilities.

Comment: Guess I am still confused on what you are after. You have an array of results being returned from facebook, and you seem to know which exactly which element you want. So are you looking for a string match on a message?

Answer (score 0):

You copied and pasted this code?

There is an extra closing curly brace at the end of line 9.

Perhaps you moved the foreach statement and now you are not terminating it properly and that is why you are only getting one iteration of the foreach loop?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. No, I didn't copy and paste but I'm not the best php coder...

Comment: I mean, did you copy and paste from your code file--is it this way in your actual code, as well?  Cause if that's the case then you've got an extra curly brace, which would not cause an error, but would cause your loop to never make it to the second iteration.

Comment: It looks like you just need to move the extra curly brace on line 9 to the last line to close your foreach loop. ;)